# Why is this fortran loop more efficient when implemented in slightly different ways?

Tags: performance, fortran, hpc

I am working with a numerical model written in fortran and there is a bottleneck in a loop. Part of the bottleneck is related to the exponentiation operator (**), which is described below. I wrote the exponentiation operation in slightly different ways and it impacts the performance. The exponent is specified as:

```
    sds_power = 2.4
```

This is the original loop, which takes for my specific case about 5 seconds to finish.

```
    DO i=istart,iend
      DO p=1,pm
        DO o=1,om
          ! these are real variables
          sds(o,p,i) = twopisds_fac*f(o)&
                     *dummy(o,p,i)*(e(o,p,i)*k4(o,i))**sds_power

        ENDDO
      ENDDO
    ENDDO
```

The loop will usually take less then 1.2 seconds, if I hard code the sds_power and change the loop into:

```
    DO i=istart,iend
      DO p=1,pm
        DO o=1,om
          ! these are real variables
          sds(o,p,i) = twopisds_fac*f(o)&
                     *dummy(o,p,i)*(e(o,p,i)*k4(o,i))*&
                                  *(e(o,p,i)*k4(o,i))*& 
                                  *(e(o,p,i)*k4(o,i))**0.4& 
        ENDDO
      ENDDO
    ENDDO
```

This [Good Programming Guide](https://www.giss.nasa.gov/staff/gschmidt/good_prog_guide.html) tells us to avoid exponentiation and to factorize the code as much as possible, which makes sense. But why does this work like this? Also, if you know other ways to improve this loop efficiency, it would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the time requited in your second loop? and when you use in the original instread of `sds_power` directly `2.4`. And why don't you use `double precision, parameter :: sds_power = 2.4d0` ?

Comment: If I understand correctly, your real question is _Why is `x**2.4D0` less efficient than `x*x*x**0.4D0`_. Is this correct?

Comment: Just a guess: Non integer exponentiation is using a series until convergence to your precision. Three multiplications and one exponentiation to a power LESS than 1 converges faster than exponentiation to 2.4

Comment: @kvantour Except there is no `D0`. If `sds_power` is a double precision variable and everything else is single precision, that could explain the difference (in the first code, there would be a conversion of `(e(o,p,i)*k4(o,i))` to double precision and then exponentiation in double precision. In the second code, no conversion and exponentiation in single precision (thus faster). The OP should clarify the types of each variable.

Comment: I concur, we need a [mcve] that includes everything and can be tested independently and the assembly can be analyzed.

Comment: @kvantour  you are right. The real question is why the first option is less efficient than the second and if it can be improved. All variables have the same precision btw. I believe the convergence issue could be the reason for it to be running faster in the second case.

Comment: @dk_sasaki Welcome to StackOverflow - the Community Policy is to use MCVE-formulated problem specification. Using a **M**inimum **C**omplete **V**erifiable **E**xample, i.e. the working state of the code + data, saves time for all Community Members and is a unique and unambiguous problem formulation. **Would you mind to complete your question as the MCVE,** in a format, that will become a fair, running and repeatable experiment -on any of the online IDE platforms- **and publish here the link for a working state MCVE?** As a Step-0, the Godbolt IDE may be used --- https://godbolt.org/z/4plNf6